# create-session stateless usage when scalling horizontally

Tags: spring, rest, spring-security, spring-boot, stateless

I want to create a RESTful API, I need it to be stateless because I might start N times the application.

I have also added the OAuth2 with jdbc implementation, user should login once and all the queries should be stateless.

Adding the following in my spring boot app crashed the login it tries now to authenticate two times.

```
    http
        .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
```

And on the server side I have these logs :

```
AuditEvent [timestamp=Tue Oct 04 05:04:52 ICT 2016, principal=dka, type=AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS, data={details=org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null}]
AuditEvent [timestamp=Tue Oct 04 05:04:52 ICT 2016, principal=anonymousUser, type=AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE, data={details=org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null, type=org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException, message=Access is denied}]
```

- Does this concern my OAuth authentication as well or only the WebSecurity part ?
- Is there a good way to configure my session in order to scale it and keep the service stateless ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your second request doesn't contain any authorization header or spring security is not evaluating it.

According to [OAuth Bearer Type Documentation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-6.1.1) your client needs to submit the header: `Authorization: Bearer YOUR_TOKEN` whereas the token is the one of your access token response (see [Example Access Token Response](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-4))

If this doesn't solve your issue, please consider to add some logs & code of your configuration.